# Conditional required based on Controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I would like to write conditional required, but condition depends on the controller where it is used.

I already have custom attribute `MyRequiredIfNot`. I just don't know how to get information about controller in `IsValid` method.

For example:

```
public class MyController1 : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Method1(MyModel model)
    { 
      //Name is required !!!
    }
}

public class MyController2 : MyController1 
{
    public ActionResult SomeMethod(MyModel model)
    { 
       //Name is NOT required !!!
    }
}

public class MyModel
{
    [MyRequiredIfNot(MyController2)
    public string Name { get;set; }
}
```

And missing implementation:

```
public class MyRequiredIfNotAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public MyRequiredIfNotAttribute(Controller controller) { }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (/*came_from ?*/ is this.controller)          //Missing !!!!
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else
            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For retriving the `Controller`, you could try `IActionContextAccessor`.

Follow steps below:

1. Register `IActionContextAccessor`

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {

       services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();

       //rest services
   }
   ```
2. `MyRequiredIfNotAttribute`

   ```
   public class MyRequiredIfNotAttribute : RequiredAttribute//ValidationAttribute
   {
       private Type _type;
       public MyRequiredIfNotAttribute(Type type) {
           _type = type;
       }

       protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
       {
           var actionContext = validationContext.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>();
           var controllerActionDescriptor = actionContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
           var controllerTypeName = controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.FullName;
           if (_type.FullName == controllerTypeName)
           {
               return ValidationResult.Success;
           }
           else
           {
               return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
           }            
       }
   }
   ```
3. Useage

   ```
   public class MyModel
   {
       [MyRequiredIfNot(typeof(MyController))]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: So awesome. Thank you.